# How does Draw Something record the drawing trace?

Tags: data-structures

For the hot APP *Draw Something*, it will record all your drawing trace and send to your friend to convey the guessword for him to guess.

How does this app record the drawing trace? In what kind of data structure?

If develop a similar white board app for real time communication, how to design the data model for more efficient and better interactive of two or more participates? (how to record the drawing trace and send to other participates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How they do it, I don't know. How I'd do it, is an array of points, where each point is either a break (which would include a colour value for the next line), or a `(X, Y, T)` tuple (coordinates and timing). This is just for freehand lines; if you need something else, obviously, it would need to be extended.

Comment: What's your records' frequency, each point change will trigger the record event, or every 10ms/100ms you check the change and record it. And if consider remote transmittal, also need to consider how to send/receiver the timeline. Any suggestion?

Comment: Timeline is included in the format I described above (`T`). The frequency, experiment and see what looks good - get the point where the lines start getting chunky if you draw a curve fast, or balance with your bandwidth. DrawSomething obviously doesn't need realtime; if you do, a persistent connection (or maybe even UDP) would be best, then you just send stuff as you get it. If you're on the web, socket.io or similar framework would work well.